# Checking database mirroring status in C#

Tags: c#, database, ado.net, mirroring

Our C# application needs to connect to SQL 2005 and 2008 databases and check what the current status of database mirroring is (eg. is it enabled, suspended, paused, disconnected etc). Are there properties where I can check this?

All our databases that are being mirrored have no witness and manual failover (synchronous mirroring).

Much appreciated if anyone can help out or point me to some documentation, google searches are not turning up much on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current state is shown in [`sys.database_mirroring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178655.aspx):

```
SELECT mirroring_state 
FROM sys.database_mirroring
WHERE database_id = DB_ID('...');
```

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365781.aspx) here describes all the System Stored procedures that will give you the information you need

> You can also retrieve or update the
>   current status by running the
>   sp_dbmmonitorresults system stored
>   procedure.

One non-obvious difference between using the sp_dbmmonitorresults and using sys.database_mirroring table that's in Remus's answer is the permissions required

#### Rights needed for sys.database_mirroring

According to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178655.aspxt) Remus referenced

> To see the row for a database other
>   than master or tempdb, you must either
>   be the database owner or have at least
>   ALTER ANY DATABASE or VIEW ANY
>   DATABASE server-level permission or
>   CREATE DATABASE permission in the
>   master database. To see non-NULL
>   values on a mirror database, you must
>   be a member of the sysadmin fixed
>   server role

#### Rights needed for sp_dbmmonitorresults

According to the previous mentioned [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365781.aspx) on mirroring SP's

> members of the sysadmin fixed server
>   role, and users who have been added to
>   the dbm_monitor fixed database role

Comment: thanks, i will look into this stored procedure, looks like it might save me writing a new one